# Read out incoming certificate in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, certificate, ssl-client-authentication

i use a tomcat http connector with client-authentification. If a client start a new connection to my server and sends his certificate, can i get the certificate and read the common name from the incoming certificate out in my java code. If yes, how?

thanks
adi

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/438788/Security/Read-client-certificate-Servlet

Look towards the end of the post. Good luck!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get the client certificate chain by getting the `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` attribute on your `HttpServletRequest`. This is an array of [`X509Certificate`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) where the first one (position 0) is the actual client certificate (the rest of the chain may be present if intermediate CA certificates are required).

```
X509Certificate certs[] = 
    (X509Certificate[])req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
// ... Test if non-null, non-empty.

X509Certificate clientCert = certs[0];

// Get the Subject DN's X500Principal
X500Principal subjectDN = clientCert.getSubjectX500Principal();
```

You can then get the various RDNs (relative distinguished name) in this principal (e.g. CN) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7634755/372643):

```
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapName;
import javax.naming.ldap.Rdn;

String dn = subjectDN.getName();
LdapName ldapDN = new LdapName(dn);
for(Rdn rdn: ldapDN.getRdns()) {
    System.out.println(rdn.getType() + " -> " + rdn.getValue());
}
```

(You could also use BouncyCastle's `X509Name` to get each RDN.)

In an X.509 certificate, the Subject DN is an ordered sequence of RDNs, each of which is a set of AVAs (Attribute Value Assertions), for example `CN=...` or `O=...`. In principle, there can be multiple AVAs per RDN, which would cause problems here, but this is very rare. You can almost assume that there is only one AVA per RDN. (Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3196955/372643) might be of interest.)

Comment: thanks, everything worked very well by first try :-)

for everybody that uses axis2 and doesn't know how to get on the HttpServletRequest:
 MessageContext context = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();
     HttpServletRequest requestProperty = (HttpServletRequest) context.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST);

Comment: I am getting null for req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate"). is it required to send request from same matching domain? I tried from both local (using localhost) machine and on development server too.

Comment: @TechnoCrat That probably means either (a) that your server isn't configured to request/require a client certificate or (b) the certification authorities list it sends when requesting a client cert doesn't match any of the client certificates you have on your machine. It's not really about "domain" matching but about CA matching.

Comment: is it require mandatory to import client certificate into server keystore to extract/read some information from client certificate? I manually exported certificate from browser and then tried to read info from that and got succeed but without exporting and using req.attribute method getting null on server.

Comment: @TechnoCrat It's the CA certificate that was used to issue the client certificate that you need to have in the server truststore (not keystore).

Answer (score 1):

Credit to mazaneicha:

```
        String cipherSuite = (String) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite");

        if (cipherSuite != null) {
            X509Certificate certChain[] = (X509Certificate[]) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
            if (certChain != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < certChaNin.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println ("Client Certificate [" + i + "] = "
                            + certChain[i].toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to get and test the cipher suite first.