# How to get SSL certificate (X.509) relevant to HTTPS request in REST controller running under Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ssl, x509certificate

I have Spring Boot REST controller that uses mutual HTTPS authentication with keystores on both server and client side. The server side has the controller class with @RequestMapping. HTTPS between server and client seems otherwise working fine.

There are multiple clients that have different they matching entries configured on the server trust store. When inside the controller body, I need to know which trust store entry has been used to authenticate the current client.

I have attempted the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945013/read-out-incoming-certificate-in-tomcat) using the injected HttpServetRequest (method parameter), but there is nothing on the request parameters. Unfortunately, seems that `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")` just returns null, even if I am sure the interaction was via HTTPS. `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite")` returns TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256.

How to get from withing the Spring Rest Controller method any information about which certificate is being used?

Spring framework 4.3.11.RELEASE, embedded Tomcat 8.0.23, Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE.

Comment: Did you enable tomcat's clientAuth and set the truststore? Try to debug the SSL connection at client or server side to ensure the client is presenting a certificate.

Comment: This comment provides answer to the question. connector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "true") is that was missing. If you convert to answer, I accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it is necessary to enable client authentication

```
Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
...
connector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "true")
```

In addition, to ensure that the client is presenting a certificate, it is possible to debug the SSL connection at client or server side

Comment: Confirmed this fixes the problem.