# When I use Request.ServerVariables("CERT_SUBJECT"), what does the value C=US mean?

Tags: asp.net, cac, server-variables, request.servervariables

When I use `Request.ServerVariables("CERT_SUBJECT")` I end up getting something like this as a string:

```
C=US, O=XXX, OU=XXX, OU=XXX, OU=XXX, CN=DOE.JOHN.JACOB.9999999
```

what does the value C=US mean? is this the cardholder's citizenship? The country of the card's origin?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.ServerVariables("CERT_SUBJECT")` gives you:

> Subject field of the client certificate.

see [Server Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

And `C` specifies `CountryName` according to [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24191_01/common/tutorials/authz_cert_attributes.html):

> An X.509 certificate consists of a number of fields. The Subject field
> is the one of most relevance to this tutorial. It gives the DName of
> the client to which the certificate belongs. A DName is a unique name
> given to an X.500 directory object. It consists of a number of
> attribute-value pairs called Relative Distinguished Names (RDNs). Some
> of the most common RDNs and their explanations are as follows:

```
CN: CommonName
OU: OrganizationalUnit
O: Organization
L: Locality
S: StateOrProvinceName
C: CountryName
```

See also [What does "subject" mean in certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650017/what-does-subject-mean-in-certificate)